# How to run installed Windows 8 along Ubuntu, after installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have a Lenovo Ideapad with pre-installed Windows 8.1 In order to install Ubuntu I disabled secure boot and changed boot mode from UEFI to Legacy. This allowed me to install Ubuntu and the grub loader is also showing an option to either boot into Windows or Ubuntu, but whenever I try booting to Windows it says `Cannot load`.

This happens because the boot order is set to Legacy mode and Windows 8 will boot only with UEFI. I am unable to access my BIOS from where I can change the boot order. I press <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd> on booting but it doesn't load the BIOS, and directly goes to the grub loader screen.

How can I make my Windows 8 run along with Ubuntu?

Comment: Simply put: Install all operating systems in UEFI mode or in legacy mode, don't mix modes. If UEFI is not working reliably consult the manual of your computer or their tech support.

Answer (score 1):

The key for BIOS might be <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in case of new laptops.

Boot into Ubuntu and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Now launch boot repair from either :

1. the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
2. or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
3. or by typing `boot-repair` in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

This will install the grub-efi bootloader. Follow the on-screen instructions given by boot-repair to complete the installation.

Now reboot your system and turn on EFI mode in BIOS. You will able to boot into both Ubuntu and Windows in EFI mode itself. The secure boot option in BIOS needs to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your Ubuntu install into EFI mode.

1. get a **64** -bit Ubuntu disk if you don't have yet
2. set your BIOS (UEFI firmware) so that it `boots USB/DVD in EFI mode`
3. boot onto your 64bit Ubuntu disk, choose `Try Ubuntu`
4. connect internet, install Boot-Repair [this way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) and use it [that way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode) in order to convert your Ubuntu install into UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this out. Is there any specific guide on how to set bios so that it boots USB/DVD in EFI mode because I could not find explicitly in my BIOS. Maybe I will look again.

Comment: You can find some examples [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode). Some firmwares propose the same option to enable UEFI boot on both HDD and USB/DVD at the same time. Others propose 2 options: one for HDD, another for USB/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

From the UEFI Page on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

> If the PC does not load Ubuntu (but instead loads Windows, for example, as in Bug #1050940), or *if the Windows entry in the GRUB 2 menu does not boot Windows* (see Bug [#1024383](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383), boot your PC using the Live CD/DVD or Live USB and choose "Try Ubuntu" once again.
>
> When the live session has loaded, run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). When Boot-Repair loads, click on the "Recommended repair" button, and write on a paper the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXXX/) that will appear. Then reboot the pc.

The UEFI page also lists other methods, and is a good resource on how to proceed.